# Most pythonic way to create a list of strings from lines in a text file?

Tags: python, string, list, text-files

From a text file `lines_of_words.txt`, say

> first
>   second
>   third

a list of words as strings has to be created, i.e.

```
list_of_strings = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

This seems like an extremely trivial function, but I can't find a concise solution. My attempts are either too cumbersome or produce a wrong output, e.g.

```
['f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '\n', 's', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd', '\n', 't', 'h', 'i', 'r', 'd', '\n']
```

or

```
first
second
third
```

What is the most pythonic function to get this done? My starting point so far has been

```
with open('list_of_words', 'r') as list_of_words:
    # Do something...
print(list_of_strings)
```

Comment: `list_of_strings = list_of_words.readlines()`. To strip newline chars `\n`, use `list(map(str.strip, list_of_words.readlines()))`

Comment: @abdusco: this will include the `'\n'` character at the end of each line.

Comment: The most pythonic way is to not read the whole file into a list, but to process the file line by line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can use `list(..)` here on the file handler. Since the strings will contain a new line, you might want to use `str.rstrip` to remove the `'\n'` part at the right:

```
with open('list_of_words', 'r') as f:
    list_of_strings = list(map(str.rstrip, f))
print(list_of_strings)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: One question: Where does `str` in `str.rstrip` point to, i.e. how does the interpreter know that `str` refers to the individual strings inside `list_of_strings`? This works fine (while e.g. `map(rstrip(), f)` does not), it's just that `str` seems to fall out of the blue.

Comment: @david: `str` referis to the `str` class. If a method it defined on the class level (and it is not a static method or class method), then `str.foo(x)` is the same as `x.foo()` given `x` is a string.

Comment: Is there a technical name for this behaviour?

Comment: @david: in mathematics, that would be "partial application". The behavior s explained here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/67579 for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('list_of_words', 'r') as f_in:
    data = [*map(str.strip, f_in)]

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['first', 'second', 'third']
```